# How to set up solr search engine using apache lucene on linux machine?

Tags: search-engine, desktop-search

Can someone suggest some desktop search engines for linux that we can use for our project work?
How to set up lucene on linux machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene installation on Linux is the same as on Windows.

Note that it is **not a desktop search engine**: [Wikipedia: Desktop Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_search).

Instead, lucene is a **programming library** for adding search functionality to your own program code.

Comment: Yes...Actually using lucene we have to set up solr search engine and I want steps for it